# To append an element into a list without generating any other elements

Tags: python-2.7

Trying to append an element into an empty list as follows, while appending it also adds a character 'u' like [u'slice'] into the empty list while adding an element into the list, however expected is ['slice']

```
Code as follows:

type = slice # value for type
value = [] 
value.append(type)
```

Output:
    value = [u'slice']

```
Requesting people for help to get output as ['slice'].
```

Comment: The "u" isn't "extra", it's part of the type.

Comment: thank you for your comment! it would be helpful if you could give me some clue, to remove the type!

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the output is in Unicode, hence the u. Try re-encoding it to ascii 
by using .encode("ascii"). Sorry I don't know why it's doing that though.